# How to add View Translated Version button in Views?

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

My site is multilingual and I have a view page of content type. If node has translation then I want to add a button/link for viewing the translation.

```
Example

View Row 1 
Title 1
Body 1 
View in English | View in Arabic

View Row 2 
Title 2
Body 2 
View Full Content

View Row 3 
Title 3
Body 3 
View in English | View in Arabic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add filter 'Translation Language' in view which can be exposed for user to select the language.

Comment: This does not create the links to "View in {language}" to each row, does it?